# Is it possible to change the background color of a native ad in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, admob

I am using "flutter_native_admob" package and I am trying to change the background color of a Native Ad but i haven´t find any way to do it.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: You can take a look at [`NativeAdmobOptions`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_native_admob/latest/native_admob_options/NativeAdmobOptions-class.html), but I don't see a background color property. Otherwise, make a `Container` with a background color that the admob widget sits in and hope the ad has a transparent background.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have already tried this and it doesn´t work because native ad has a default black background.

Comment: Then your options are either crack open the package code and change it yourself or accept the black background. (Keep in mind that changing the package code might get you in trouble with the ad publishers later. These ad packages generally have black backgrounds by default for a reason.)

Comment: Okay, thanks, I would accept the black background.

Comment: is it allowed by google admob to change background color?

Answer (score 0):

use container over that screen(where you want to show ad) and keep your background (Colors.(you want to show for ad);) then go to Adsense/Admob and select ads for website.
For reward ad no option as of now (DataTime.now();).

Comment: Please provide a descriptive answer and/or possible code examples.